# How to set android:ellipsize with both properties i.e.. end & marquee?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am facing problem while setting android:ellipsize in listview. Actually as per my requirement when textview(in list view row xml file) is having 32 characters it should append "..." at the end and when user has focus on that list item then it should auto scroll horizontally (which is marquee)

```
android:id="@+id/navigation_item_text"
        style="@style/PlaylistNavigationText"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
```

I have tried few approaches:
1) manually set  android:ellipsize="end" in layout file and in listview's setOnItemSelectedListener pragrammatically done that

```
TextView titleTextView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_item_text);
                titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

But the problem is that case it will not change to ... again.

2) Tried On listview adapter tried focuschangelistener on textview

```
if (hasfocus){
titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
}else{
titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
}
```

Nothing works. Any suggestion will be welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Set `android:ellipsize="end"` in layout file

```
android:id="@+id/navigation_item_text"
    style="@style/PlaylistNavigationText"
    android:layout_width="204dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
```

2) Call setSeletected(true) of TextView class

```
    if (hasfocus){
        titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        titleTextView.setSelected(true);
    }
```

This way you will get your result

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. It becomes marquee when has fucus but no " ..." once it lost focus

Comment: Editted my answer.. pls check now